# Why is my Google app script creating corrupt zip files?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The zip file that my Google app script creates is "difficult" to open in Window desktop. The zip won't open in File explorer, but I can get it open in the program 7zip.  The files are created from columns in Google sheets (of mixed text and numbers).  Notepad++ says that they are encoded in UTF-8, and the DXF file has been changed to one line of comma separated values.  The file is too large to manually fix since it is normally around 100,000 lines.

If I don't zip the files, the google app script rejects the DXF file as unsupported.  The DXF file is text file with a column of text that AutoCAD can interpret.  I can change the DXF extension to TXT and email it separately, but I want the file to have the right extension.

**Edit (2019-04-02):** My current issue is emailing or downloading a usable DXF from the third sheet of the spreadsheet.  I can do this manually, but I want to make things as easy as possible for anyone using this file.  Eventually, I will modify the generic DXF file with the (x,y) locations of the structures along with the descriptive text for each structure, although the script below does not do that at this time.  Thank you!

**Edit 2 (2019-04-08):** Based on the suggestion, I found some code to format the data into a CSV array: var csv = ""; dxfValues.forEach(function(e1) {csv += e1.join(",") + "\n";}); 
Adding this code creates a readable, usable DXF file from a column in Sheets.  It handles some of the weirdly formated characters and lines in the DXF file without dropping them or mashing them together.

```
        var values = ss2.getDataRange().getValues();
        var filename = JobNumber + ' Structures Dips ' + new Date().getTime() + ".txt";
        DriveApp.createFile(filename, values);

        var dxfValues = ss3.getDataRange().getValues();

        var dxf_Filename = JobNumber + ' Structures Dips ' + new Date().getTime() + ".dxf";  // DXF file name
        var folder = "---folder id---"; // Folder ID

        var csv = "";
        dxfValues.forEach(function(e1) {csv += e1.join(",") + "\n";});

        var url = DriveApp.getFolderById(folder).createFile(dxf_Filename, csv, MimeType.CSV);

        var Dipblob = DriveApp.getFilesByName(filename).next().getBlob();
        var DXFblob = DriveApp.getFilesByName(dxf_Filename).next().getBlob();


        var zip = Utilities.zip([Dipblob , DXFblob]);


        MailApp.sendEmail({
                           to: "--email address---",
                           subject: filename,
                          htmlBody: "Hello <br><br>" + "Here are the generated dip files",
                           attachments: [zip],
                           name: 'Scot May'
                          });
       }
```

I would like to either have an emailed zip file with the text file and the DXF file, or an email that has filename.txt and filename.dxf attached to it.   Thanks.  ** issue resolved, see above **

Comment: The fact that Windows Explorer doesn't open the zipfile does not mean it is corrupt. The v-arious Windows Explorer implementations of zip have had gaps from the beginning. They typically have had trouble with large files and spanned files. If 7zip works why not use that?

Comment: My goal is to distribute this Google sheet, script, and form to other people in my company.  I don't want to force them to use 7zip, for ease of adoption.  (edit - also, I didn't know that about Windows)

Comment: If you are going to distribute, stop right there and create an add-on. You only want to have one thing to update.

Comment: I will do that.

Comment: Include in your question an example sheet data layout and an example of the correct DXF file that should be created.

Comment: I added a published link to the spreadsheet, and it contains the DXF file on its own tab. The DXF file is generated from a simple, empty AutoCAD template with 100 multileaders (i.e. text with a line/arrow attached).   I updated the code above, but it's a work in progress.  Thanks

Comment: Can you update your problem description too, to reflect the current issues that you're not able to address?

Comment: I added my current evolution of my problem, which is downloading or emailing a DXF file from the third sheet of the spreadsheet.

Comment: tehowch -- thanks for your help!  I resolved my problem this weekend using var csv = "";  dxfValues.forEach(function(e1) {csv += e1.join(",") + "\n";});  It seems to handle the weird stuff in the DXF file, and I was able to open the DXF in AutoCAD.  Without your suggestion, and identifying what my actual issue was, I wouldn't have been able to fix my code!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Probably your issue with the "erroneous" content format in the DXF is resolved by properly creating the file from a 2D array.

As an example, this function converts a 2D array into a CSV:

```
/**
 * Construct a CSV representation of an array. Adds quoting and escaping as needed.
 * @param  {Array[]} myArr A 2D array to be converted into a CSV string
 * @return {string} A string representing the rows of the input array, joined by CRLF.
 */
function array2CSV_(myArr)
{
  return myArr.map(_row4CSV).join("\r\n");

  /**
   * Ensure the given value is CSV-compatible, by escaping special characters and adding double-quotes if needed.
   * @param  {any} value An array element to be encapsulated into a CSV string.
   * @return {string} A string that will interpreted as a single element by a CSV reader.
   */
  function _val4CSV(value)
  {
    const str = (typeof value === 'string') ? value : value.toString();
    if (str.indexOf(',') !== -1 || str.indexOf("\n") !== -1 || str.indexOf('"') !== -1)
      return '"' + str.replace(/"/g, '""') + '"';
    else
      return str;
  }
  /**
   * Construct a CSV representation of in the input array.
   * @param  {Array} row A 1-D array of elements which may be strings or other types which support toString().
   * @return {string} A string that will be interpreted as a single row by a CSV reader.
   */
  function _row4CSV(row)
  {
    return row.map(_val4CSV).join(",");
  }
}
```

It looks like the DXF format is a single column, so you'd probably join `row` with `" "` instead of a comma. Perhaps DXF doesn't also require the same escaping that CSVs do, so your implementation of the value formatter could very well be simpler too.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this, and let you know.

Comment: @scot any luck?